# NaN gradients while Training (but loss isn't NaN neither the computational graph is disconnected)

Tags: tensorflow, python, backpropagation, gradient-descent

The reason I am asking this here is that I haven't found a bug in my code and maybe there isn't a bug at all (or maybe there is). I just want to validate the idea that I am trying to implement. Here is my idea.

I am trying to estimate a function `g` using some `basis` function(s) $f_i$'s where $i = 1,\dots, n$. Further, for generalizability, I am introducing $4$ transformations to the set of basis functions that help in the construction of $g$ from $f_i$, $i=1, \dots, n$. The transformations are $T_1: x \to a_1.x$; $T_2: x \to x^{a_2}$; $T_3: f_i(x) \to  b_1.f_i(x)$; $T_4: f_i(x) \to f_i^{b_2}(x)$. With these transformations introduced, I want to estimate $g$ as the `sum` of $n$ $f_i$'s transformed using *all* four transformations. (Note that an identity transformation corresponds to $a_1 = a_2 = b_1 = b_2 = 1$.

As a starter, I tried to learn a set of transformed $f_i$'s using the basis functions which by default have the identity transformation. With the short prelude to my objective, I now present my codebase which can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ElswPqWOH8hp7gcrsRsi3GguIVxONgR/view?usp=sharing). Anyone can download the `code.zip` file and run `nn4.py` which should get the code running.

My problem though is that, while training a neural network, for predicting the parameters of transformations i.e., $a_1$, $a_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$, I get the gradients to be `NaN` despite trying very small learning rates and several initializations. My training pipeline is as follows:

> Suppose the function to be estimated is `g`. Step 1: Give samples from $g$ to the neural network $NN$ and obtain the set of parameters $a_1$, $a_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$ for all basis functions. (Effective dimension of output is thus $n \times 4$ is $n$ is the number of basis functions) Step 2: Reconstruct the function $g$ by substituting the parameters into each basis function and then adding up all the basis functions. Step 3: Calculate the mean squared error between the samples of the reconstructed function and the samples from the original function. Step 4: Backpropagate this loss

I have ensured that $g$ (the function we are trying to estimate) is scaled between $[-1, 1]$ and the all $f_i$'s are also scaled to $[-1, 1]$ as well. However, scaling the parameters would not make sense in this context so I didn't scale them.

I have no idea, as to why the gradients are coming `NaN`. I have verified that the loss isn't `NaN`. Also one important observation that I made is that the parameters given by the $NN$ is `NaN` from the 2nd step itself (1st step is initialization). I couldn't find a bug in my code so I thought there might be a conceptual bug in the idea.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue. Any help/comments are greatly appreciated.